# How to extend a partition in Windows 2000 Server

Tags: windows, partition

I have a Windows 2000 Server set up with RAID 5.  I initially defined 2 136 GB logical disks 0 and 1.  I have a small utility partition on disk 0 along with the C drive.  I wish to extend the C drive to use disk 1 as well, which is now configured to drive D.  I deleted drive D, but it is still in disk 1.  I download partdisk.exe from MS, but am not sure how to accomplish what I want to do.  I know I need to use extend, but I think I need to remove disk 1 and somehow add the unallocated space to disk zero, but am not at all confident on how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it very difficult to manage the disks in Windows XP / Server with the built in tool: Disk Management. I think you have to use a third party product / tool to do you job without loosing data. Check out this tutorial with some freeware: http://www.geeksdo.com/resize-server-partition-wizard-server.html (only for Servers)

For home PC: http://www.geeksdo.com/howto-resize-partition-with-partition-wizard-home-edition.html

An comparison for partition tools: http://www.geeksdo.com/server-partition-software-review.html

Comment: Sorry marc_s.  I saw the categories and thought that it was fine.  What is the diskspace and hardware categories for?  Are they for like driver coding?

Comment: This doesn't work on Windows 2000 Pro.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure, is this will work under Win 2000 Server. Run this from command line or "start->run". This is easier than command line tools.

```
diskmgmt.msc
```

What kind of controller is this? Maybe you can use software from Adaptec, Dell or other manufacturer.

Answer (score 0):

You seems want to extend disk o partition with the unallocated space of disk 1, however you have not configured RAID configuration. And your disk 0 contains system partition. So that is a little diffecult. To extend system partition with the space of another disk is not realistic. In you situation you have to prepara a bigger disk and replace the system disk, you could choose migrate OS tool: [migrate os to another bigger hard drive](http://www.extend-partition.com/help/migrate-system-wizard.html)

Answer (score 0):

Did you config the disk as hardware raid 5? However, from your description, it seems like you did not use the hardware raid 5. 
First raid5 need at least 3 disks, (there just two in your description, disk0 and disk 1)
Second if you set raid 5 successfully, it will list as one disk in disk management (not two).

Therefore, you need to make sure your raid 5 is config in a right way. If you only have two disks I suggest you'd better set it as raid 0. BTW, if you want to resize partition on windows server OS, you could try Partition Assistant Lite which is a free partition software for Windows Server OS. Here is an article about how to resize partition on SERVER OS. Hope it could help you
http://www.partition-magic.org/free-server/resize-server-partition-free.html

Answer (score 0):

i use Partition Magic
[visual help about this tool](http://www.partitionmagicserver.com/resize-partition/partition-magic-windows-2000-server.html)

[click here : article about diskpart](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/325590)